# WSHttpBinding TransportWithMessageCredential SecurityMode alters request

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, ws-security

I am struggling with `WCF` binding configurations.I have third party service added as reference to my project. I was provided with some specifications.

I need to use `SOAP v1.2` so I figured that I need `WSHttpBinding` it's going to be `https` so I need `SecurityMode.Transport`

Something like this:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
var client = new MyClient(binding, addr);
var result = client.Method(new MyObject());
```

It results in this request body.

```html
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"      
            xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
  <S:Header>
     <wsa:MessageID>
       uuid:6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA
     </wsa:MessageID>
     <wsa:ReplyTo>
       <wsa:Address>example</wsa:Address>
     </wsa:ReplyTo>
     <wsa:To>example</wsa:To>
     <wsa:Action>example</wsa:Action>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
     <MyObject>...</MyObject>
  </S:Body>
 </S:Envelope>
```

According to the specification I was provided I need to include `Security` element in Header with `UsernameToken` and `Timestamp`. Exactly what I would get with `BasicHttpBinding` and `BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential`

When I try to set `TransportWithMessageCredential` mode with `WSHttpBinding` request body changes drastically.

```
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
var client = new MyClient(binding, addr);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "123456";
var result = client.Method(new MyObject());
```

```html
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"      
            xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
  <S:Header>
     <wsa:MessageID>
       uuid:b633067e-9a9e-4216-b036-4afa3aca161e
     </wsa:MessageID>
     <wsa:ReplyTo>
       <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
     </wsa:ReplyTo>
     <wsa:To>example</wsa:To>
     <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</wsa:Action>
     <o:Security s:mustUnderstand=1 xmlns:o=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd>
      <u:Timestamp>...<u:Timestamp>
      <o:UsernameToken>
      <o:Username>...</o:Username>
      <o:Password>...</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
     </o:Security>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
     <t:RequestSecurityToken>...</t:RequestSecurityToken>
  </S:Body>
 </S:Envelope>
```

Now I have the security part correct, but all the addressing part is wrong and the body as well. What should I do?

I was expecting(and I need) something like this:

```html
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"      
            xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
  <S:Header>
     <wsa:MessageID>
       uuid:6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA
     </wsa:MessageID>
     <wsa:ReplyTo>
       <wsa:Address>example</wsa:Address>
     </wsa:ReplyTo>
     <wsa:To>example</wsa:To>
     <wsa:Action>example</wsa:Action>
     <o:Security s:mustUnderstand=1 xmlns:o=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd>
      <u:Timestamp>...<u:Timestamp>
      <o:UsernameToken>
      <o:Username>...</o:Username>
      <o:Password>...</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
     </o:Security>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
     <MyObject>...</MyObject>
  </S:Body>
 </S:Envelope>
```

Comment: I recommend you try the steps in there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776403/wcf-create-usernametoken-with-timestamp-and-password-digest-for-oasis-200401-w

Answer (score 0):

The second packet you posted is not a WCF call request but a part of security channel setup. This is `RequestSecurityToken` packet that will be answered with `RequestSecurityTokenResponse`. After that, if the channel is set up correctly, the same packet with method call will be sent as you posted in first snippet. You can see this packets sequence in Service Trace Viewer:

[image]

What is the actual problem you're trying to fix? Does your WCF call fail? If so please provide exception details. The most likely reason is WCF configuration or authentication error.

If you strive to avoid these negotiation packets, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810763/5740031) that shows how to switch `SecurityMode` to `Message` and set `NegotiateServiceCredential` option to `false`.

**UPDATE:**

This part is related to question update that asks for fixing addressing part of the request.

To manually set wsa:ReplyTo header you need to set [ReplyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageheaders.replyto.aspx) property of [OperationContext.OutgoingMessageHeaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.outgoingmessageheaders.aspx), like this:

```
using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.ReplyTo = new EndpointAddress("http://someclient/callback");
    var request = client.Method(new MyObject());
}
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158642/5740031) for more details.

Comment: ty for your answer. I updated the question and provided request body I need.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I had to use `CustomBinding` to send desired request.

```
var b = new CustomBinding();

var security = TransportSecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
    security.IncludeTimestamp = true;
    security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
    security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.Default;
    security.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;
    security.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;

var encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
    encoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10;

var transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
    {
       MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
       MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
       MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
    };

    b.Elements.Add(security);
    b.Elements.Add(encoding);
    b.Elements.Add(transport);

var client = new MyClient(binding, addr);
var result = client.Method(new MyObject());
```